# How to control do not register with the same username

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I added users to register to enter username, but, what is the algorithm to control another user does not register with the same username?

```
def control_username
    if user.username.present?
      if user.id.nil?
        if User.exists?(:username => user.username)
          redirect_to root_path
        end
        user.save!
      end
    else
      redirect_to new_user_session_path
    end
end
```

I added this method in 'users_controller.rb'. Is that correct? I am using the gem 'devise'.

Comment: Why not to control it in the model? `validates :username, presence: true, uniqueness: true`

Comment: Thank you! I haven't noticed, I appreciate it!

Comment: @Grych, your your comment is actually the correct answer, not just a comment :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to the model:

```
validates :username, presence: true, uniqueness: true
```

Optionally, if you also want to enforce uniqueness on the database level and your DB allows it, add this to the migration

```
def change
  add_index :users, :username, unique: true
end
```